# how do I make my image hover?

Tags: css, hover, onmouseover

I am trying to make my logo hover on mouseover and it is not working. I have two images uploaded to my server. Here is the code and her is the url.What is wrong?

http://arabic001.com

```
<div id='logo'>
            <a href="/index.html">
                <img src="/images/logo001H.png" style="display:none">
                <img src="/images/logo001.png"
                    onMouseOver="this.src='/images/logo001H.png'" 
                    onMouseOut="this.src='/images/logo001.png'">
            </a>
        </div>
#logo {
    position:absolute;  
    text-align:center;
    top:20px;
    right:10px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: not an answer to your question - but: the absolute positioning of #wrapper is a *very* bad idea - makes your site completely inaccessible on small browser windows.

Comment: thank you so much for this tip. I have been having difficulties with the issue of positioning with exactly what you just mentioned. I was waiting to solve some of the other problems before I get to that. What is the best way to position my wrapper so that small browser windows will not cut off the top part?

Comment: i'd just stick to regular positioning - and just add horizontal centering with 'margin: 0px auto' - that way visitors on small screens still get scrollbars. i understand you want central positioning, but since your design is pretty big, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Javascript expert, but I wouldn't use Javascript for this.

Try the following CSS:

```
a.logo { /* and add class="logo" to the a-element */
    display:block;
    width:150;
    height:105px;
    background:url(/images/logo001H.png) no-repeat;
}    
a.logo:hover {
    background:url(/images/logo001.png) no-repeat;
}
```

And remove the img's...

Answer (score 1):

I propose you use css sprites.

http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Your html code will look something like this:

```
<div id='logo'>
    <a href="/index.html"></a>
</div>
```

And css code:

```
#logo a{ 
    text-align:center;
    top:20px;
    right:10px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    cursor:pointer;

    background: url(/images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
#logo a:hover{
    background-position: 0 -150px;
}
```

Your final image will contain both images: default and hover.